# Cannot call method 'html' of null

Tags: jquery, html

I'm getting an issue with jQuery:

> Cannot call method 'html' of null

Code:

```
var currenthtml = $('div.welcome').html();
var newhtml = ' Mod Loaded';
var totalhtml = currenthtml+' '+newhtml;
$('div.welcome').html(totalhtml);
```

I try to load it the first time, it fails, then if I do it the second time, it works.

Comment: Is the DOM ready when you're first doing it?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZVvQ/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Bj539/ The problem is somewhere you're not showing. Even running this before domready wouldn't cause that error. Are you sure the error message is pointing to this piece of code? Have you loaded jQuery before this script?

Comment: Is jquery called before this code?

Comment: I launch it on document ready.

Answer (score -1):

Please check,

whether your jquery code is written within `$(document).ready(function()` function of JQuery or not.

Also you can try to write your JQuery Code at end of the HTML.

As we have seen your issue, we understand that first time when the JQuery code is executing, the HTML DOM is not getting the `'div.welcome'` part.

Hope this help you.

Thanks.